# What is the closest Pentadactyl/Vimperator clone for Opera?

Tags: opera, vimperator, pentadactyl

I'm a firefox+pentadactyl fan - but sometimes I'm forced to work in Opera. What is the closest pentadactyl analogue (in terms of default keys and functionality) in Opera (I find that there are several of similar ones)?

**Edit**:

Pentadactyl/Vimperator brings one keyboard browsing - see [screenshots](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/screenshots). But I mostly using it not for the hints - but for the browsing. That is `S` ask for string to be searched in google. `d` kills tab. `P` inserts an address from the clipboard, `y` copies the current page's address to the clipboard. And so on.

Comment: Please briefly explain what those extensions do, so Opera users can suggest you more options, and people looking for their functionally may find your post.

Comment: My condolences for being "foced to work in Opera", easily the most customisable browser out there. The ability to assign pretty much any key to pretty much any command can be quite a handicap. (Forgive the sarcasm, but I felt I should point out that your approach to asking this question isn't the most inspiring.)

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean to start a flame. Two thigs though: firefox (xulrunner actually) has a partial selection method - hold ctrl and drag the mouse here and there. Also hold ctrl - and drag the mouse over the table - You will capture the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check :[Blazeix blog](http://my.opera.com/Blazeix/blog/vimperator-for-opera)

or

[VimOperate](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/vimoperate/0.3.2/?display=en)

Comment: Which of them got automatically updated by Opera?

Comment: None,  Opera have a lot build-in shortcut, but doesn't provide any Vim shortcut support

Comment: I can't find vimoperate's docs... Not even a list of keybindings.

Answer (score 4):

VimOperate only works with Opera 11 and 12, but Opera now allow you to install Chrome extensions.

So just install Vimium.

1) Install opera extension which allows you to install Google Chrome Web Store extensions  - https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/

2) Install the Vimium extension at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en

You now have a a great looking Vimium extension working in Opera.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Keybindings not works. Even after restart of the browser.

Comment: @skywinder Well I switched to Vivaldi. It is much more like old Opera  https://vivaldi.com/?lang=en_US

Vivaldi is a freeware web browser developed by Vivaldi Technologies, a company founded by Opera Software co-founder and former CEO Jon Stephenson von Tetzchner and Tatsuki Tomita. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivaldi_(web_browser)